# Where can I find a website that allows me to ask for book recommendations on electronics?

Tags: discussion

before you close this for being off topic or for whatever other reason can you please just shoot me a private message or something where can I find a website that allows me to ask for book recommendations on electronics?

I'll delete my account to not pester this website any further.

I just bought The Art of Electronics 3rd edition and EMC by Ott off of amazon. Are there better books out there that might go into more specifically motor drivers and actuator drivers and how to protect the electronics (like an H-bridge) from some of the natural characteristics (avoiding mosfet gate ringing, etc) and unnatural environment (electromagnetic noise, etc) that the load might be susceptible to?

Comment: FWIW, EEVblog is probably the best forum for discussion. Also, don't discount the old fashioned ways: any library can at least get you started, with university libraries and faculty being the most promising for technical topics. Don't be afraid to e-mail, phone or meet with local professors, either.

Comment: I don't think there is a private messaging system on SE.

Comment: As I mentioned on your previous question: you can ask for recommendations in [chat].

Comment: It seems like you want this Stack Exchange site to be something which it is not. This is not a social network. If you want features like discussions, recommendations, etc., then unfortunately you're in the wrong place. It's like you're going to the library to buy milk. It's unfortunate if this frustrates you, but this is not indented to be the ultimate resource for everything.

Comment: As you seem to suspect, SE is not designed for this type of questions. I'm wondering why you don't use one of the many other methods to obtain information. For instance, a quick web search got me to [this promising reddit topic](https://old.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/wiki/education)

Comment: @velvet cheers for an actual answer. You're right I shoulda just done a google search, will be deleting this account, thx

Answer (score 1):

This site is a Q&A site, not a search engine, the mission of the site is to build a repository of good questions and answers. What happened with SE is they found time and time again that these types of questions did not lead to good questions and answers so they decided to close these types of questions.

Answer (score 1):

Too late for the OP, but

For a forum that supports discussion I suggest that people look at http://www.piclist.com (don't be put off by the presentation or the PIC in the name). Then visit http://mailman.mit.edu/mailman/listinfo/piclist, join the mailing list & say hello. Provide as much detail of your requirements as possible.

Just like here, there are people there who know almost everything (collectively).
The site supports a conversational approach.
Some SE members are also PICList members (myself included).
It's a very useful complement to this site for questions of this sort.

Answer (score -10):

Just go to chat where you can ask roughly zero active chat users and then in a few weeks maybe get a non answer like "yeah there are probably books out there"